# Change CSS class depending on div size

Tags: html, css, container-queries

So with @media screen - you are able to change CSS depending on screen size. I am looking for a way to change the CSS according to Div size

So if

```
#menu-logo is > 250px {
     do this
} or else {
     do that
}
```

Is there any way to do this with CSS ? I'm trying to make my website responsive. Thanks

Comment: You could visit these links for help. [Line25](http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-responsive-web-design-with-media-queries), [ugurus](http://www.ugurus.com/responsive-design-media-queries)

Comment: No, you would need to use Javascript to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with regular media-queries at what point your div will be greater then 250px and just use that value in your media-query. Targeting the div itself will need jQuery though.